# Angular 6 list stagger animation shows list items twice

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I have an observable based list that points to a Firebase realtime database entry and I want to add an animation for whenever an element is added or removed from the list.

My problem is that the animation is shown correctly on the initial page load (if the list is already populated with some items - shown at the end of the animation below) - however the animation has an unusual side effect when an element is added (or to be more precise, it happens for every element after the first):

[image: Animation problem]

As you can see - at the end - when I refresh the page the items are all animated correctly, but when I add them one after the other the inner elements are displayed twice, one animated and one static, and when the animation is done, the second element vanishes.

I have had the problem before with the list elements as well (yet the inner elements were displayed only once). I solved this by adding the trackBy function. Then the list elements were not displayed twice any longer but the inner elements were (as you can see in the picture).

This is what I got so far:

overview.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf='userOrders | async as userOrdersFromContainer'>
  <div [@listStagger]="userOrdersFromContainer.length">
    <div *ngFor="let userOrder of userOrdersFromContainer; trackBy:identify">
      <user-order [userOrder]="userOrder"></user-order>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

overview.ts:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'user-order-overview',
 templateUrl: './user-order-overview.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./user-order-overview.component.css'],
 animations: [
  trigger('listStagger', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(
        ':enter',
        [
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          stagger(
            '50ms',
            animate(
              '550ms ease-out',
              style({ opacity: 1 })
            )
          )
        ],
        { optional: true }
      ),
      query(':leave', animate('50ms', style({ opacity: 0 })), {
        optional: true
      })
    ])
  ])
]
})
export class UserOrderOverviewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    userOrders: Observable<UserOrder[]>;
    ngOnInit() {
       this.userOrders = this.orderService.loadUserOrders(this.groupOrderId);
    }

    ...

    identify(index, item) {
       return item.userId;
    }
}
```

ListElement.html:

```
  <h6>{{userOrder?.displayName}}</h6>

  <div *ngFor="let userOrderItem of userOrderItems()">
  {{userOrderItem?.name}} {{userOrderItem?.price | currency:'EUR'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

ListElement.ts:
Doesn't contain anything important I think.

Comment: After a while I am pretty sure now that the ':enter' and ':leave' target everything within the overview component. And since the userorderitems (name+price) are a list nested within a list 'userOrders' they are affected as well. The problem is that even after an hour of trial and error I have not found a way of limiting it. 'user-order:enter' did not work, whereas 'div:enter' did. I'd be happy if someone could point out my error here